# ¿como convertir en python 3 los datos provenientes de un archivo CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, lista

Estoy trabajando en Python 3, al leer un archivo .CSV con varias columnas, de las cuales las 3 ultimas tienen números. Al leer el archivo, todas las columnas las lee como strings y yo deseo que tengan formato int o float.

¿Cómo puedo convertir las columnas 5, 6 y 7 a números enteros o flotantes?

Gracias

mi código es el siguiente:

```
dato_produc = 'produccion_diaria2.csv' #nombre del archivo a leer
 with open (dato_produc, 'r') as produccion:
      produccion = produccion.read().splitlines() #divide los registros en lineas

datos_produccion = []
for l in produccion:
    line = l.split(',') # separa cada dato con una coma
    datos_produccion.append([line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8]]) #Crea una lista con los datos obtenidos del archivo CSV
 datos_produccion.remove(['indice_planta', 'fecha', 'linea', 'turno', 'supervisor', 'lbs_totales', 'IngUtil', 'merma']) # elimina la primera fila que contiene los titulos para poder hacer operaciones aritmeticas
 print (datos_produccion) # imprime la lista que se ha creado.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El casting se hace tal y como te muestra Patricio Moracho en su respuesta, no obstante, si tienes libertad para usar cualquier librería y vas a operar con los datos te recomiendo que consideres el uso de [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Lo puedes instalar usando `pip` y aparte de facilitarte mucho las cosas tendrás una gran diferencia en cuanto a eficiencia y posibilidades.

Un ejemplo de `produccion_diaria2.csv`:

> indice_planta,fecha,linea,turno,supervisor,lbs_totales,IngUtil,merma
>   2,2017/04/01,1,4,A,1524,45,14
>   1,2017/05/01,1,5,B,147,75,12
>   1,2017/05/21,1,4,C,1478,41,14
>   2,2017/05/14,1,4,A,1457,41,5
>   2,2017/05/04,2,4,D,1475,14,2

Cargamos el csv en un DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("produccion_diaria2.csv",  parse_dates=['fecha'])
```

**Los datos son convertidos al tipo adecuado según su compatibilidad de forma automática, aunque también podemos indicarlo de forma explícita.** Especificamos que se parsee la fecha de forma explícita a tipo `datetime`.

Podemos ver nuestra tabla:

```
>>> df
   indice_planta      fecha  linea  turno supervisor  lbs_totales  IngUtil  merma
0              2 2017-04-01      1      4          A         1524       45     14
1              1 2017-05-01      1      5          B          147       75     12
2              1 2017-05-21      1      4          C         1478       41     14
3              2 2017-06-14      1      4          A         1457       41      5
4              2 2017-06-04      2      4          D         1475       14      4
```

Ahora podemos usar todas las herramientas que Pandas pone a nuestra disposición para operar, filtrar y agrupar datos. Unos ejemplos muy básicos:

Seleccionamos solo las filas que sean de Mayo del 2017:

```
>>> df1 = df[(df["fecha"].dt.year == 2017) & (df["fecha"].dt.month == 5)]
>>> df1

   indice_planta      fecha  linea  turno supervisor  lbs_totales  IngUtil  merma
1              1 2017-05-01      1      5          B          147       75     12 
2              1 2017-05-21      1      4          C         1478       41     14
```

---

Seleccionamos las filas que tienen `indice_planta` con valor 2 y `supervisor` "A":

```
>>> df2 = df[(df["indice_planta"] == 2) & (df["supervisor"] == "A")]
>>> df2

   indice_planta      fecha  linea  turno supervisor  lbs_totales  IngUtil  merma
0              2 2017-04-01      1      4          A         1524       45     14
3              2 2017-06-14      1      4          A         1457       41      5
```

---

Obtener la suma de la columna `merma` para la planta 1:

```
>>> df[df["indice_planta"] == 1]["merma"].sum()
26
```

---

Obtener una nueva columna resultado de restar `merma` a `lbs_totales`:

```
>>> df["lbs_reales"] = df["lbs_totales"] - df["merma"]
>>> df

   indice_planta      fecha  linea  turno supervisor  lbs_totales  IngUtil  merma  lbs_reales
0              2 2017-04-01      1      4          A         1524       45     14        1510  
1              1 2017-05-01      1      5          B          147       75     12         135 
2              1 2017-05-21      1      4          C         1478       41     14        1464
3              2 2017-06-14      1      4          A         1457       41      5        1452 
4              2 2017-06-04      2      4          D         1475       14      2        1473
```

Comment: Me queda claro el uso de pandas. Yo estaba pensando utilizar Numpy y fue cuando me atoré al formar las series. De cada columna. Gracias

Comment: @AlejandroGomez Pandas de hecho usa NumPy por debajo y sus tipos de datos, pero esta pensado para operar con conjuntos  grandes de datos  tabulados como los que tu presentas de forma eficiente, teniendo multitud de métodos pensados para el manejo y análisis de esos datos así como el manejo de documentos CSV, Excel, etc. Puedes usar Python estándar con listas o diccionarios anidados, pero operaciones tan simples como las anteriores van a necesitar mucho más código y van a ser mucho menos eficientes.  Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes razón  gracias

Answer (score 0):

Las conversiones de estos datos las puedes hacer mediante:

- [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para convertir una cadena a un entero
- [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) para convertir a un dato de punto flotante

Por ejemplo:

```
datos_produccion.append([line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], int(line[6]), float(line[7]), int(line[8])])
```

Ten en cuenta que la cadena sea válida, es decir, pueda convertirse al tipo de dato elegido, en caso contrario Python emitira una Excepción del tipo `ValueError`